# Number of prime factors of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an integer $n$, can somebody give me a formula to find (approximately) number of prime factors $n$ has?

Comment: There's no easy answer to this. Just the question "is the number equal to 1 or not?", i.e., testing whether a number is prime, is a [difficult subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Comment: Prime testing, and factorization, are two of the hardest numerical problems out there.

Comment: Maybe this could provide you with some starting point: http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega(n),_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardy and Ramanujan proved that for almost all integers, the number of
distinct primes dividing a number $n$ is given by

> $$ \omega(n) \sim \log\log n. $$

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say $~$? An upper bound? Is it log base e?

Comment: See here for a precise definition of what is meant here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order_of_an_arithmetic_function